# Does Azure have a FREE tier?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I recently started to use Azure with the goal to host this:

1. A Python Web API
2. A Blazor Web App

This is just for testing and I dont care about authentication, database or performance.

The 1-Year trial already expired for me (I tried it once and never used it...).

1. Is it possible to host my scenario in Azure for free?
2. In the "Pay-as-You-go" I have to pay approx. 70€ per month, which is ridiculous (I saw my bill just now...). I forums people say to change the subscription to the "Free Tier". But I dont have that option. Did microsoft remove this?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the Azure service, you can use free or cheap options for hosting.

Your web apps can run in an `App Service Plan` with the tier Free where you have 60 of minutes free daily. You can use both `Windows` and `Linux` to host your application however please note that `Free Tier` option is only available when you choose `Windows`. It is not available on `Linux`.

See here for reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/pricing/details/app-service/windows/ (English version: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/).

Comment: Yeah I saw that one as well. But I didnt find it in my options for the app service plan. I just dint have the "Free Tier". I only have "Pay as you go"

Comment: `I just dint have the "Free Tier". I only have "Pay as you go" ` - "Free Tier" is available in Windows hosting only. May be you're using Linux as the hosting platform.

Comment: :). You should be able to host your Python Web API in Windows as well. Please create a new Windows App Service Plan with Free tier, then create a new Web App with Python in that App Service Plan and deploy your API there.

Comment: So, I checked again and again... If I go to "Subscriptions" in Azure I only get: "Free Trial" (not eligible), "Pay a you go", "Azure Students".  I do not have the option for the Free Tier. I am so confused now.

Comment: The subscription is independent of the Azure app service plan tier. You'll have to choose `Pay as you go` for the `Subscription` and in the `App Service Plan` for your `App Service`, you need to go to `Scale up` and then `Dev/Test` and then `F1`

Answer (score 1):

"Pay as you go" is a type of subscription.

You pay for the resources that you use. Except for the resources that are free.

For example a VNET and a resource group do not cost anything.

There is also a free tier to the App Service Plan, that allows you to run app services for free.

Answer (score -2):

No, I don't think they have a free tier.  IIRC they give you some starting credits to try stuff, and then you have to pay.

Comment: :( ok thanks. This "25 always free services" bullshit is annoying. Its like "Buy now for free (but $99.99 shipping)"

Comment: That’s not correct. Azure App Service had a “Free Tier” which allows you to host your web application for free. It comes with some limitations though.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info.  I stand corrected.

Comment: "had" a free tier? So it does not have one anymore?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It is still there.

Comment: Please see details of Free plan here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/ (same link shared by Tobias, only in English).